# How to give validation to a date time field in Directus

Tags: directus, directus-flows

I have a DateTime field in my table named as "scheduled_at". I want give validation to this date time field where the value should be greater that or equal to now.

I have tried applying filters to this field with values 'scheduled_at' Greater than or equal to $NOW, and I have also tried creating a conditional flow but I did not get any output. Or may be my approaches were wrong.

[image: Validation Page]
[image: Flow Page]
[image: 'scheduled_at' Field]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the moustache syntax {{$now}}?
Note: syntax should be included between "".

Comment: Cam you elaborate? What syntax do you mean?